# Are Cache-control: pre-check and post-check headers still supported by IE?

Tags: http, internet-explorer, browser, http-headers, browser-cache

I found [information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250440(v=vs.85).aspx) that Internet Explorer 5 or maybe IIS 4.0 introduced support for the pre-check and post-check Cache-control headers. I haven't been able to find much info on if they are still supported in later versions such as IE 8, 9, 10 & 11.

I want to remove support for them in an application but want data that they are no longer used.

Comment: "If you want to prevent caching, do not include the post-check and pre-check directives. Doing so is completely unnecessary and results in wasted bandwidth and HTTP header processing cycles." Found this article that actually says our use case is unfounded. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/07/20/using-post_2d00_check-and-pre_2d00_check-cache-directives.aspx

Comment: I just proposed to remove these from Drupal, https://www.drupal.org/node/2646280, because we used them incorrectly anyways. "If both post-check and pre-check are specified and set to 0, both are entirely ignored."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the replies on [your tweet](https://twitter.com/ElijahLynn/status/685195442498473985) from the people that know what they're talking about, the pre-check and post-check headers may be supported, but their use is discouraged.

(just posting for posterity)

> Yeah, short answer is that nobody should use these and all uses of "p*check=0" are junk.
>
> I left p*check support in WinINET in the IE9 rewrite & I doubt removed since, but urge you to not use.
>
> ~ Eric Lawrence, Internet Explorer engineer who wrote the pre-check/post-check header code
>
> sources:
>
> - https://twitter.com/ericlaw/status/685201170260819968
> - https://twitter.com/ericlaw/status/685201463987929088